# Spark submit from windows vs. linux

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm experiencing with Spark (2.3.0) over Kubernetes in the past few days.

I've tested the example SparkPi from both linux and windows machines and found the linux `spark-submit` to run ok and give my proper results (spoiler: Pi is roughly 3.1402157010785055)
while on windows spark fails with class path issues (`Could not find or load main class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi`)

I've noticed that when running `spark-submit` from linux the classpath looks like that:
`-cp ':/opt/spark/jars/*:/var/spark-data/spark-jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar:/var/spark-data/spark-jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar'`

While on windows, the logs show a bit different version:
`-cp ':/opt/spark/jars/*:/var/spark-data/spark-jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar;/var/spark-data/spark-jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar'`

Note the : vs. ; in the classpath which I think is the cause for this issue.

Suggestions how to `spark-submit` from windows machine without the classpath issue?

This is our `spark-submit` command:

`bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6443 \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name spark-pi \
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
    --conf spark.driver.memory=1G \
    --conf spark.driver.cores=1 \
    --conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
    --conf spark.executor.cores=1 \
    --conf spark.executor.memory=500m \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:2.3.0 \
    http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9080/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can overwrite the environment variable `SPARK_MOUNTED_CLASSPATH` in the script `$SPARK_HOME/kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/entrypoint.sh`, such that the wrong semicolon is replaced by the correct colon.

Then you need to rebuild the docker image, e.g., with `$SPARK_HOME/bin/docker-image-tool.sh`. After that, spark-submit on Windows should work.

See also Spark issue tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24599